# What is the best way to sync data near real-time from Ali Cloud SQL Server to Azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Our production application is running based on an Ali Cloud SQL Database. But our reporting service needs to rely on Azure SQL Server.

What is a good solution to sync data between this two environments? Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) to sync data from any cloud server or on-prem to Azure SQL server.

Hope it helps.